# C# Stored procedure without parameters

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I am trying to run a stored procedure without parameters using a class that inherits from dbcontext. This is my code:

```
MyDBContext _myDBContext = new MyDBContext();
_myDBContext.Database.SqlQuery("MyStoredProcedure", new SqlParameter());
```

But this does not work as it is looking at the wrong overload. Even though I am using a string then params object[].

If I have parameters in there, it works. I have done this with other stored procedured e.g.:

```
IEnumerable<MyClass> tempMyClass =
_myDbContext.Database.SqlQuery<MyClass>(
    "myStoredProcedure @ID",
    new SqlParameter("@ID", 5));
```

Any idea where I am going wrong?

### MyDBContext Definition

```
class MontagueDBContext : DbContext, IUnitOfWork 
{ 
    public MontagueDBContext() : base("name=MontigueApp") 
    { 
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()); 
    } 

    public IDbSet<Permit> Permits { get; set; } 

    public void ChangeEntityState<TEntity>(TEntity item, EntityState entityState) where TEntity : class 
    { 
        this.Entry(item).State = entityState; 
    } 

    public EntityState GetEntityState<TEntity>(TEntity item) where TEntity : class 
    { 
        return this.Entry(item).State; 
    } 

    public new int SaveChanges() 
    { 
        return base.SaveChanges(); 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are telling EF that there is a single parameter (albeit one without a name or value!).

Change your code to the following:

```
_myDBContext.Database.SqlQuery("MyStoredProcedure");
```

### Background

The [params](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx) keyword is a special keyword that allows a method to take zero or more arguments.

### EDIT

You can execute raw SQL statements in various ways, but this is probably the best for your scenario (executing a stored-procedure that returns no results and is not tied to a specific table).

```
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("EXEC MyStoredProcedure");
```

See [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/jj592907.aspx) for a bit more background information and various alternatives.

Comment: Sure there is - [this one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.sqlquery(v=vs.113).aspx#M:System.Data.Entity.Database.SqlQuery``1%28System.String,System.Object[]%29) takes a string and an **optional** array of parameters. Note that this takes a generic parameter, but I assumed you just didn't show that in your first piece of code, as you have it in your second piece of code.

Comment: Sorry, can you please show me what you mean by a generic parameter? My second piece of code used a specific parameter (I think).

Comment: Hmmm, it seems that by adding a random class into the sqlquery, I was able to run it: '_myDBContext.Database.SqlQuery<randomClass>("MyStoredProcedure");' I haven't tested it worked in the database yet though.

Comment: That's going to cause a runtime error most likely - you are telling EF that the results of your stored procedure can be converted to that type (which I'm assuming is not the case...)

Comment: My stored procedure does not return a result. `MyDBContext` does not have a DbSet parameter. I am guessing it gets that from inheriting from DbContext.

Comment: Can you paste the definition of MyDBContext? I think that will clear my confusion up :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98587/discussion-between-rb-and-alan-schapira).

Comment: Tested `context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("EXEC MyStoredProcedure");` this morning. Worked a treat. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like this can help..

```
      private const string SAMPLE_SP_NAME = "dbo.sp_your_sprocname_here";

      ...

      yourDbcontext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("EXEC " + SAMPLE_SP_NAME);
```

apologies for the edits.. original example posted is in case returning something out from sproc ...

```
     DbRawSqlQuery<string> sprocReturnOutput =
                    yourDbcontext.Database.SqlQuery<String>("EXEC " + SAMPLE_SP_NAME);
```